# How can I create a relay server using tulip/asyncio in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the [example echo server](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-protocol.html#echo-server)

```
import asyncio

class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
        # Client piece goes here

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServer, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
print('serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exit")
finally:
    server.close()
    loop.close()
```

What I'm trying to do is add a client piece where I've commented that will connect to a new server and send the data off that-a-way. There's the [echo client](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-protocol.html#echo-client), but I need a process that looks like this:

```
    +-----------+    +-----------+    +--------------+
    | My Server |    | My Client |    | Other Server |
    +-----------+    +-----------+    +--------------+
          |                |                 |
 ===>Get some data         |                 |
          |                |                 |
      Send data ---------->|                 |
          |                |                 |
          |            Send data ----------->|
          |                |                 |
          |                |              Do Stuff
          |                |                 |
          |                | <-----------Send Data
          |                |                 |
          | <--------- Send data             |
          |                |                 |
 <=== Send data            |                 |
          |                |                 |
          |                |                 |
          |                |                 |
          |                |                 |
```

Obviously I can do this synchronously, but I'm trying to make the `client -> other server` bit async, and I'm not really figuring out how to use the `asyncio` methods to communicate between my server piece and a client piece.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a simple proxy which allow you to `wget 127.0.0.1:8888` and get a html response from google:

```
import asyncio

class Client(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.connected = True
        # save the transport
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        # forward data to the server
        self.server_transport.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, *args):
        self.connected = False

class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    clients = {}
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        # save the transport
        self.transport = transport

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_data(self, data):
        # get a client by its peername
        peername = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        client = self.clients.get(peername)
        # create a client if peername is not known or the client disconnect
        if client is None or not client.connected:
            protocol, client = yield from loop.create_connection(
                Client, 'google.com', 80)
            client.server_transport = self.transport
            self.clients[peername] = client
        # forward data to the client
        client.transport.write(data)

    def data_received(self, data):
        # use a task so this is executed async
        asyncio.Task(self.send_data(data))

@asyncio.coroutine
def initialize(loop):
    # use a coroutine to use yield from and get the async result of
    # create_server
    server = yield from loop.create_server(Server, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# main task to initialize everything
asyncio.Task(initialize(loop))

# run
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Why? I've already used this kind of references. Any traceback or useful error message...?

Comment: `Exception in callback <bound method _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready of <asyncio.selector_events._SelectorSocketTransport object at 0x7f1c5d10e198>> ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 38, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 486, in _read_ready
    self._protocol.data_received(data)
  File "the_test.py", line 9, in data_received
    self.client.transport.write(data)
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'client'
`

Comment: Upon further examination of the asyncio docs, the value yielded as `server` is not actually an instance of `Server` - it's some kind of wrapped(??) value

Comment: You were right. It's not that simple. My new example works for me. Hope it will put you on the way.

Comment: Nice! That seems to work, should get me headed in the right direction.