# Why does asyncio.open_connection (or any other coroutine) prevent data_received from processing?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following code slightly modified from the [asyncio documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-protocol.html#echo-server)

```
import asyncio
asyncio.tasks._DEBUG = True


class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        name = transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection:',name,'<--',peername)
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        name = self.transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
        peername = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')

        print('Got data:',name,'<--',peername,':',data.decode() )
        if name[1] == 8888:
            print("Making connection")
            reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8889, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
        else:
            self.transport.write(data)

        self.transport.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro_1 = loop.create_server(EchoServer, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
coro_2 = loop.create_server(EchoServer, '127.0.0.1', 8889)
server_1 = loop.run_until_complete(coro_1)
server_2 = loop.run_until_complete(coro_2)
print('Serving on {}'.format(server_1.sockets[0].getsockname()))
print('Serving on {}'.format(server_2.sockets[0].getsockname()))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("^C caught, exiting")
finally:
    server_1.close()
    server_2.close()
    loop.close()
```

However, when I run this, it doesn't appear to even *run* the `data_received` function:

```
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 8888)
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Connection: ('127.0.0.1', 8888) <-- ('127.0.0.1', 36580)
```

But when I comment out the `yield from` line, it runs the way I would expect.

```
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 8888)
Serving on ('127.0.0.1', 8889)
Connection: ('127.0.0.1', 8888) <-- ('127.0.0.1', 36581)
Got data: ('127.0.0.1', 8888) <-- ('127.0.0.1', 36581) : Hi, gaise!
Making connection
```

I've tried adding:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def do_a_thing():
    print("hey, it's a thing!")

def try_stuff():
    print('Trying')
    yield from asyncio.async(do_a_thing())
```

and calling `try_stuff` instead. This does output "Making connection", but not 'Trying'. By changing the `yield from` line to a simple call does output 'Trying'. And if I remove the coroutine decorator from `do_a_thing` then I get the output.

The important thing to me is that I'm trying to create an async connection to the 2nd server. But evidently, the presence of the `yield from` prevents any further processing (at least that I can tell - it certainly stops with the print).

So what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield from` **must** be used in a coroutine. As I can see, data_received can't be a coroutine because of some asyncio internals.

A solution is to wrap your code in a coroutine and call it using a asyncio.Task().

As an example you can have a look at my [experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295068/how-can-i-create-a-relay-server-using-tulip-asyncio-in-python/21297354#21297354)

Comment: It appears you are correct, by creating another method and wrapping it in the `@asyncio.coroutine` method, I was able to get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

As gawel mentioned, `yield from` must be used in a coroutine, and despite the fact that the Server class is within some asyncio calls, the functions are not magically coroutines.

`EchoServer` needs to look like this:

```
class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        name = transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection:',name,'<--',peername)
        self.transport = transport

    # This is where the magic happens
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_data(self, data):
        print("Making connection")
        reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8889)
        print("Connection made")
        writer.write(data)
        print("Data sent")
        # For some reason, not providing n caused this to not return anything
        resp = yield from reader.read(1024)
        print("Got response")
        self.transport.write(resp)
        print('Data returned:',resp)

    def data_received(self, data):
        name = self.transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
        peername = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')

        print('Got data:',name,'<--',peername,':',data.decode() )
        if name[1] == 8888:
            print("making task")
            asyncio.Task(self.send_data(data))
            print("done making task")
        else:
            print("Sending response")
            self.transport.write(data[::-1])
```